# How to alter the positions of multilevel columns in a dataframe using Python?

Tags: python, pandas, dataframe

I have the following df:

```
       a           b
    x  y  z     x  y  z
```

But, I want to alter the positions of the multilevel columns: I want to have:

```
       x       y      z
     a   b   a   b  a   b
```

How can I do that? Sorry for not being able to provide you with the code.

Much thanks.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Let us try `swaplevel`

```
df=df.swaplevel(1,0,axis=1).sort_index(level=0,axis=1)
```

Comment: Perfect! Thank you!

Comment: Done! Thanks again. Sorry for delay!